# Assign a documents values as a <Type>

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

Making an Observable <Hero[]> out of a collection works perfectly and gives me access to all its documents, but I am unable to assign individual documents. The recurring error message is the following:

> Type 'Hero | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Hero'.

The working code for collections:

```
export class DataManagerService {

    heroesCollection : AngularFirestoreCollection<Hero>;
    heroesData:Observable<Hero[]>;
.
.
constructor(private firestore:Firestore){

    this.heroesCollection = this.firestore.collection<Hero>('HEROES');
    this.heroesData = this.heroesCollection.valueChanges();  
.
.
getHeroes():Observable<Hero[]>{

    return this.heroesData;
```

Then I use this return in other components:

```
heroes : Hero[]=[];

  getHeroes():void{
    this.DataManagerService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroes =>this.heroes=heroes);
  }
```

But when it comes to documents:

```
  heroDocument : AngularFirestoreDocument<Hero>;
  public heroData:Observable<Hero>;
```

```
  this.heroDocument = this.firestore.doc('Z8NylmZfeUIuQnmaz2cy');
  this.heroData = this.heroDocument.valueChanges();
```

```
getHero(id:number):Observable<Hero>{ 
    return this.heroesData;
  }
```

I receive this error message:

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Hero'.  return

> this.heroData=  this.heroDocument.valueChanges();

Comment: The result of `this.firestore.doc(...)` is possibly undefined since there may not be a document with the provided identifier. You need to check that the result is not undefined before trying to set `this.heroDocument = this.firestore.doc(...);`.

Comment: I tried this check:

if(this.heroDocument){
  this.heroData = this.heroDocument.valueChanges();}

I still have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a subscription to the document instance:

`this.itemDoc.valueChanges().subscribe(hero=>this.hero = heroData as Hero);`